# Плагин JS для отсеивания по версии браузера

Tags: javascript, jquery, browsers

К примеру, есть задача отсеять браузеры, с которых заходит пользователь, чтобы дать предупреждение о том, что всё поедет, в случае если пользователь зашёл с древнего браузера. К примеру, имеем такой список отсеивания: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox.

Существует ли поддерживаемый плагин для голого JS или jQuery, чтобы влепить попап вроде такого?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скриншоте плагин http://jreject.turnwheel.com, но он, к сожалению, последний раз обновлялся в 2014 году — нету поддержки мобильных браузеров.

Comment: По хорошему нужно проверять не версию браузера, а фичи, которые вам нужны.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть вот эту библиотеку: https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin
пол года назад на проекте показала себя весьма неплохо. может и вам поможет).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как правильно прокомментировали - эта задача делится на две. **Первая** - определить, что браузер пользователя не поддерживается сайтом. **Вторая** - отобразить окно, максимально совместимое со всеми древними браузерами.

Вторая задача по прежднему прекрасно решается плагином http://jreject.turnwheel.com . Для первой задачи, как написал @Alexey Ten , необходимо проверить доступность критичных фич.

К примеру решение по вопросу (попап при отсутсвии поддержки flexbox):

```
var tst = document.createElement("div");
var flexSupportCaps = [
    tst.style.flex, 
    tst.style.flexWrap, 
    tst.style.flexFlow,
    tst.style.flexGrow,
    tst.style.alignContent, 
    tst.style.alignItems, 
    tst.style.alignSelf, 
    tst.style.justifyContent, 
    tst.style.order
];
if (flexSupportCaps.indexOf(undefined)!=-1){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.reject({
            reject: { all: true }, // Reject all renderers for demo  
            header: 'Браузер не поддерживается', // Header Text  
            paragraph1: 'Вы используете устаревший браузер.', // Paragraph 1  
            paragraph2: 'Для корректной работы портала vashsite.ru рекомендуем установить один из следущих браузеров, или обновить ваш до последней версии.',
            closeLink: 'Закрыть окно',  
            closeMessage: 'Я согласен с тем, что отображение сайта может быть некорректно.',
            imagePath: '/externals/jReject-master/images/',  
            closeCookie: true,
            browserInfo: {
                msie: {
                    text: 'Microsoft Edge',  
                    url: 'https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/microsoft-edge'  
                }
            }
        }); 
    });
}
delete tst;
```

Выявляется поддержка flexbox, если её нет, то выплёвывается попап плагина jReject. Выплёвывается он единожды, о чём говорит параметр `closeCookie: true` .

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Bowser

Если мне необходимо

1. Написать предупреждение для некоторых устаревших браузеров, что контент страницы сайта может отображаться некорректно;

или

2. Выводить в одном браузере один текст, во втором другой — [**реальный пример**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/560571/199934);

Пользуюсь библиотекой [**bowser**](https://github.com/ded/bowser).

---

### 2. Характеристики bowser

1. Возможность отсеивания по типу браузера — мобильный или десктопный, — операционным системам, движкам и наименованиям.
2. Поддержка не самого популярного ПО: например, Sailfish OS, Tizen, K-Meleon или Sleipnir.
3. Простота использования. Подключаем bowser без дополнительных зависимостей через атрибут `src` тега `script` и пишем скрипты. Синтаксис скриптов:

```javascript
if (bowser.$флаг для браузера, движка, ОС или типа устройства) {
    // Здесь пишем поведение, которое будет только у пользователей браузеров, объявленных флагом.
}
```

```javascript
if (bowser.$флаг для браузера, движка, ОС или типа устройства && bowser.version <= $Номер версии: поведение, описанное ниже между {фигурными скобками}, будет применяться к версии под данным номером и версиям, которые ниже её. ) {
// Здесь пишем поведение, которое будет только у пользователей браузеров, объявленных флагом, в версиях, ниже или равной указанной.
    }
```

---

### 3. Демонстрация

В данном примере

- во всех версиях браузеров на движке Trident, как то Internet Explorer, будет выводиться один текст;
- в браузерах на движке Gecko, начиная с 50 версии, другой;
- пользователям браузеров на Gecko ниже 50 версии будет показано модальное окно с предложением использовать более новую версию;
- юзеры остальных браузеров увидят пустой результат.

```html
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="http://fenixrepo.fao.org/cdn/faostat3/js/bowser/1.0/bowser.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#SashaBowserExplorer,
#SashaBowserFirefox {
    color: mediumvioletred;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
</style>
<div id="SashaBowserFirefox"></div>
<div id="SashaBowserExplorer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Отображение в браузерах на движке Trident <= 11 MSHTML.dll версии
if (bowser.msie) {
    var SashaBowserExplorer = document.getElementById("SashaBowserExplorer");
    SashaBowserExplorer.innerHTML = "Саша умнейшая, Она не станет пользоваться Internet Explorer.";
    // Отображение в браузерах на движке Gecko <= 49
}
// Отображение в браузерах на движке Gecko <= 49
else if (bowser.gecko && bowser.version <= 49) {
    alert('Пожалуйста, используйте новые версии браузеров на движке Gecko, чтобы прочесть, насколько же Саша совершенна.');
}
// Отображение в браузерах на движке Gecko > 49
else if (bowser.gecko) {
    var SashaBowserFirefox = document.getElementById("SashaBowserFirefox");
    SashaBowserFirefox.innerHTML = "Саша легендарная!";
}
</script>
```

Как выглядит результат выполнения данного кода в браузерах:

*Internet Explorer 11.576.14393.0*

[image: IE]

*Firefox 31.0*

[image: Old Firefox]

*Firefox 50.1.0*

[image: New Firefox]

---

### 4. Дополнительная ссылка

- [**API bowser**](https://github.com/ded/bowser#api).

Answer (score 1):

Вместо отсеивания браузеров, лучше определять поддержку той или иной фичи, например с помощью [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/).

В противном случае придется поддерживать актуальность вашей базы совместимых браузеров. К примеру браузер X не поддерживает нужной вам возможности, вы его добавляете в "черный список", через полгода выходит свежая версия с нужной фичей, и если теперь не обновить условия, он по прежнему будет считаться "не подходящим" для вашего сайта. Другая ситуация - выйдет очередной "яндекс" браузер, про который ваш сайт ничего не знает.

Для упомянутого вами flexbox проверка через modernizir может выглядить так (с дополнительным условием - поддержкой flexwrap):

```
if (Modernizr.flexbox && Modernizr.flexwrap) {
  // Modern Flexbox with `flex-wrap` supported
}
else {
  // Either old Flexbox syntax, or `flex-wrap` not supported
}
```