# Как сделать так, чтобы разные браузеры обрабатывали разный код?

Tags: javascript, html

Существует ли возможность указать в `HTML`, чтобы определённые браузеры обрабатывали отдельно для них созданный `JS/JQuery`? И как это сделать?

Comment: Конкретно в html  такое сделать вряд ли, а в JS можно определить браузер по userAgent и уже в зависимости от этого выполнять заготовленный код.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin   новый вопрос здесь писать без смысленно , можешь проконсультировать ?

Comment: на Mozilla.org - Идентификация браузера на основе обнаружения строки агента пользователя является ненадежной и не рекомендуется, так как строка пользовательского агента настраивается пользователем.

Comment: Мне кажется, вы в не ту сторону копаете. Очень мало существует случаев, когда `js` работает по разному в разных браузерах. Вы лучше приведите пример кода, который в разных браузерах работает по разному.

Comment: Посмотрите [**данный ответ**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/611507/199934). Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных код можно посмотреть здесь - https://github.com/evgenjnr/evgenjnr.github.io/tree/master/weatherapp_land, а вот реализация - https://evgenjnr.github.io/weatherapp_land/#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конкретно в html такое сделать вряд ли, а в JS можно определить браузер по userAgent и уже в зависимости от этого выполнять соответствующий код.

```js
let isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
let isFirefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;
let isIE = navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' || !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/) || navigator.userAgent.match(/rv:11/));

if (isChrome) {
  alert('Это хром');
}
if (isFirefox) {
  alert('Это мозилла');
}
if (isIE) {
  alert('Это IE');
}
```

Comment: Обычно парсить руками userAgent - так себе идея. Там всё сложнее.

Answer (score 4):

Вообще это делается через JS, но для IE ниже версии 10 существовали условные комментарии. Обозреватель сети IE поддерживает возможность определения версии под названием «условные комментарии»:

```
<!--[if условие]> невидимый HTML-код <![endif]-->
<![if условие]> видимый HTML-код <![endif]>
```

Логическое НЕ можно использовать для создания стиля, который будет доступен во всех браузерах кроме IE. Условные комментарии игнорируются этими браузерами, они воспринимают их как обычные комментарии HTML. Поэтому необходимо изменить код следующим образом.

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
  Для всех браузеров кроме IE
<!--<![endif]-->
```

В первой и третьей строке добавляется `-->`, обозреватели сети воспринимают эти строки как комментарий и не обрабатывают их. Internet Explorer в свою очередь считает их условными комментариями и обрабатывает их.

IE версии 10 обрабатывает их, если страница загружена в `standards mode`.

**Смотрите также:**

- [Условные комментарии](http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/internet-explorer/uslovnye-kommentarii)
- [Conditional comment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment)

Comment: т.е. в <!--[if !IE]>-->  Для всех браузеров кроме IE<!--<![endif]--> можно указать скрипт который будет выполняться JS или JQ для определённых браузеров

Comment: @EvgeniyR, можно не только JS/JQ, но даже HTML, CSS и всё прочее, что отображается и обрабатывается на клиенте.

Comment: а кроме IE к примеру Хром или Файерфокс можно указать, просто у меня Js Firefox-om красиво обрабатывается а остальными браузерами не очень, в IE саВсЭм не работает

Comment: @EvgeniyR, нет, нельзя. Можно только IE и все остальные.